# Screen turns black after pressing volume button

Tags: unity, compiz, lenovo

I don't know why but my laptop screen (Lenovo Thinkpad SL300) suddenly turns black after turning down the volume and then comes back, with ugly problems, after turn it up. It started happening after doing some changes on Compiz.

Can you help?

Comment: Please try unity --reset in terminal

Answer (score 1):

**Answered by OP in comments**

An installed program called Jupiter was the problem. I uninstalled it and I no longer get the black screen when I use the volume buttons.